# Angular find which nested group a control name belongs to

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to find which nested group a control belongs to.

My simple form:

```
this.form= this.fb.group({
  firstName: ['', [Validators.required]],
  lastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
  nestedForm1: this.fb.group({
    name1: [ '', [Validators.required]]
  }),
 nestedForm2: this.fb.group({
    name2: [ '', [Validators.required]]
  })
});
```

I want the name of the nested group.
Example: name1 belongs to nestedForm1 and name2 belongs to nestedForm2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AbstractControl.parent` property on the control itself. Read more about the type AbstractControl [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl).

Comment: Yes that is true but i need to find the group name.